# AlreadyClosedException during AMQP connections auto-recovery using Spring AMQP

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We encounter occurrences of the following exception in the logs of our Java applications bound to a Rabbit MQ instance.

It is something that must be taken care of, denoting a problem in the implementation of Spring AMQP or is it something that could be ignored ? In the latter case, what could be the root cause of such errors ?

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:927)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.close(AMQConnection.java:1042)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.close(AMQConnection.java:971)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.close(AMQConnection.java:955)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.close(AutorecoveringConnection.java:305)
   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.close(SimpleConnection.java:76)
   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory$3.handleRecovery(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:389)
   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory$3.handleRecoveryStarted(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:383)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.notifyRecoveryListenersStarted(AutorecoveringConnection.java:652)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.beginAutomaticRecovery(AutorecoveringConnection.java:570)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.access$000(AutorecoveringConnection.java:63)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection$3.recoveryCanBegin(AutorecoveringConnection.java:513)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.notifyRecoveryCanBeginListeners(AMQConnection.java:754)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.doFinalShutdown(AMQConnection.java:731)
   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:615)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It seems that the implementation of the `com.rabbitmq.client.RecoveryListener` interface in `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory` unconditionally closes the connection no matter of its "opening" state.

```
@Override
public void handleRecoveryStarted(Recoverable recoverable) {
   handleRecovery(recoverable);
}

@Override
public void handleRecovery(Recoverable recoverable) {
   try {
      connection.close();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      AbstractConnectionFactory.this.logger.error("Failed to close auto-recover connection", e);
   }
}
```

`spring-amqp` and `spring-rabbit` versions are 1.7.14

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should not use auto recovery with Spring; it has always had its own recovery mechanisms, years before the amqp client.

There are some strange corner cases where we can't co-exist with it and end up with orphaned consumers. We tried to patch around it several times over the years, but gave up and now simply stop the recovery before it starts.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell - The `CachingConnectionFactory` constructor indeed raises a warning when using auto-recovery. More specifically, it mentions potential occurrence of Spring `AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException`, but nothing about Rabbit MQ client `AlreadyClosedException`. 

Shall these two exception types (the Spring one and the Rabbit MQ one) be considered identically in such a context ?

Comment: The `NotCurrentlyOpenException` needs code in your app to deal with it; the other one is just noise in the log (which we should clean up). But, why not take my advice and simply disable auto recovery?

Comment: Thanks - Just wanted to make sure that nothing was missed out as part of the problem analysis.